# Pydub, cannot locate mp3 file (OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory)

Tags: python, pydub

While trying to use an mp3 file in a python environment I get this error, my file directories are all properly spelt.

Note: the directories are formatted so that within a project folder there is the main code, and 2 sub-folders one for the non-altered mp3 files ("targets"), and one for the altered mp3 files ("altered_targets").

I have already tried to switch AudioSegment.from_file("filename","mp3") with no luck.

```
from pydub.playback import play
from pydub import AudioSegment
import sys
import os

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ffmpeg')

def adjust_volume(file_name, adjustment):

   song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file_name)

   new_song = song + adjustment

   new_title = "./alter_targets/%s" % (file_name)

   new_song.export(new_title, format='mp3')

for target in os.listdir("./targets"):
   adjust_volume("./targets/"+target, 10)
```

This code snippet should slightly increase the volume of the mp3 file within "targets", then save the new mp3 file into the "altered_targets" file.

Instead I get "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "volume_alter.py", line 19, in <module>
    adjust_volume("./targets/"+target, 10)
  File "volume_alter.py", line 10, in adjust_volume
    song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydub/audio_segment.py", line 716, in from_mp3
    return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3', parameters=parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydub/audio_segment.py", line 665, in from_file
    info = mediainfo_json(orig_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydub/utils.py", line 263, in mediainfo_json
    res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: You're using `./`, meaning it'll only look for files in the current directory

Comment: @JammyDodger, can I not use "./targets/file.mp3" ?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the code. Can you get it to print out `"./targets/"+target` before it runs `adjust_volume()` to see if it's looking for a correct path?

Comment: Also which line is the error on?

Comment: @JammyDodger "song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file_name)"

Comment: Check to make sure `from_mp3` allows passing in a subfolder

Comment: @JammyDodger, I changed my code slightly so that from_mp3 does not need to navigate to a sub-folder but it still gave me the same error.

Comment: I would suggest to use `os.path` to manipulate your path variable (e.g. `new_title = os.path.join([os.path.dirname(__file__), 'alter_targets', file_name])`)

Comment: Sometimes, depending on how you invoke a script, the working directory of the process is not where you would expect, so relative paths do not resolve as you would expect. You can see what the working directory of the process is by calling `os.getcwd()`. If it is not the parent directory of `targets`, then you know why you're seeing this error.

Comment: @Alex, good suggestion but upon checking it is not the source of my issue.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback you're receiving?

Comment: @Alex, I updated the question to include the traceback